# How do I convert EGM96 Heights to EGM2008 Heights?

Tags: geodesy, vertical-transformation

I have a bunch of points with Latitude and Longitude in WGS84 Datum, and Heights in EGM96. I need to convert the Heights to EGM 2008.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your input data is in CSV format, then you can do this using QGIS & GDAL as follows:

1. Create a shapefile with lat-long coordinates. (i.e EPSG: 4326)
2. Use the 'Set Z value' Tool in the toolbox and use the Z values to set the coordinates of each point to be 3 Dimensional.
3. On the command line, run the following command `ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:9707 -t_srs EPSG:9518 output.shp input.shp`. You are telling gdal, that input data is in [EPSG:9707](https://epsg.io/9707) (*WGS84 for horizontal coordinates, and EGM 96 for vertical coordinates*) and the output should be generated in [EPSG: 9518](https://epsg.io/9518) (*WGS84 for horizontal coordinates, and EGM 2008 for vertical coordinates*)
4. Add this new file to Qgis, and using the field calculator, Add the Z Values to a new column.
5. Export the attribute table to CSV format.